# Python PIL image open and save changes image file size?

Tags: python, image, file, compression, python-imaging-library

I used PIL to open and save the same jpg image, but the size reduces significantly. Could somebody explained what's going on under the hood?

I run

```
a = Image.open('a.jpg')
a.save('b.jpg')
```

a.jpg has the size 5MB, whereas b.jpg is only 600KB. and I enlarge them and compared side by side and basically see no differences in the picture quality. Could somebody explain this?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default save quality for jpg in Pillow is 75. I bet your original image is saved with a higher quality setting.

> The image quality, on a scale from 0 (worst) to 95 (best), or the string keep. The default is 75. Values above 95 should be avoided; 100 disables portions of the JPEG compression algorithm, and results in large files with hardly any gain in image quality. The value keep is only valid for JPEG files and will retain the original image quality level, subsampling, and qtables.

From https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg