# Why is image opening and saving using PIL increasing its size

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm doing the following :

```
im = Image.open("input.png")
im.save("output.png")
```

My input image is around 350kB and the output image around 2.2MB. The quality parameter doesn't seem to work for PNG as it does for JPG in PIL. I have tried using OpenCV as well for this but the same thing happens. Why does this happen and how do I resolve this without changing the extension or losing quality?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python PIL image open and save changes image file size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286223/python-pil-image-open-and-save-changes-image-file-size)

Comment: In fact, there's no `quality` parameter, cf. [Pillow's PNG doc](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png). Have you tried `compress_level`? Nevertheless, without knowing which special kind of PNG compression your original PNG has, you won't get similar results when plain saving PNG using Pillow. I'm afraid, you're comparing apples and oranges here.

Comment: @HansHirse yes my bad, can we though reach the same result through `compress_level` and `optimize` PNG parameters ?

Comment: Please use the proper internationally-accepted SI units, else your 2.2MB (megabytes) looks like 2.2mb (millibits). M=mega. m=milli. B=byte, b=bit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: @Younes it does not sadly, as mentioned, PNG does not have a `quality` parameter. I did try both `compress_level` and `optimize` but neither of them resolved the problem. 
@MarkSetchell will keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: If you'd care to share your **original** PNG file (maybe using Dropbox or Google Drive so that imgur doesn't strip/alter it) it may be possible to work out what is going on.

Comment: try:  im.save("output_optimize.png", optimize = True) and tell us about the size

Comment: or try im.save("output_compression.png", compress_level = 9)